# Saving in iOS paint app

Tags: ios, xcode, save, nsuserdefaults, paint

I'm having a bit of trouble with saving the paint strokes in my iOS app. I've successfully saved text in my app by using NSUserDefaults, but I'm not sure if saving images works the same way, anyways, here's what I have:

```
-(IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *saveImage = drawImage.image;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:saveImage forKey:@"image"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Whenever I hit the save button in my app (saveImage), Xcode's output responds by saying, -`[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<UIImage: 0x1f076ee0>' of class 'UIImage'`.

I'm not sure what this means. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm new to Xcode and Objective-C. Thanks for your help, 
-Karl.

Comment: I don't think you really want to save an image in the user defaults. You want to save that in the documents folder, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to save a `UIImage` as a value in your `NSUserDefaults`. What you need to do is convert the `UIImage` to `NSData` and save that instead.

```
-(IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *saveImage = drawImage.image;

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage)];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefault` are not able to save `UIImage` directly but you can save them as `NSData`. For this  convert the image firs and then save this

```
  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(drawImage.image);
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];
  [defaults synchronize];
```

For converting NSData back to an UIImage use imageWithData:  e.g.

```
 UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```